# Rotate my Object with Mouse and Touch (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch

I have a Problem that I just discovered a few days ago and the Problem is that I cant rotate my Object on a Surface with Touch because I only can Rotate it via Mouse and my question is what do I have to add to my Simple Mouse Roatator Script?

Im a beginner with C# and Unity so hopefully somebody could help me here.

Here is the Code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

namespace UnityStandardAssets.Utility
{
    public class SimpleMouseRotator_E : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // A mouselook behaviour with constraints which operate relative to
        // this gameobject's initial rotation.
        // Only rotates around local X and Y.
        // Works in local coordinates, so if this object is parented
        // to another moving gameobject, its local constraints will
        // operate correctly
        // (Think: looking out the side window of a car, or a gun turret
        // on a moving spaceship with a limited angular range)
        // to have no constraints on an axis, set the rotationRange to 360 or greater.
        public Vector2 rotationRange = new Vector3(70, 70);
        public float rotationSpeed = 10;
        public float dampingTime = 0.2f;
        public bool autoZeroVerticalOnMobile = true;
        public bool autoZeroHorizontalOnMobile = false;
        public bool relative = true;
        public GameObject reflectionprobe;

        public Vector2 startPos;
        public Vector2 direction;
        public bool directionChosen;

        private Vector3 m_TargetAngles;
        private Vector3 m_FollowAngles;
        private Vector3 m_FollowVelocity;
        private Quaternion m_OriginalRotation;

        private bool whileDragging;

        private void Start()
        {
            whileDragging = false;
            m_OriginalRotation = transform.localRotation;
        }


        private void Update()
        {
            // Track a single touch as a direction control.
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

                // Handle finger movements based on touch phase.
                switch (touch.phase)
                {
                    // Record initial touch position.
                    case TouchPhase.Began:
                        startPos = touch.position;
                        directionChosen = false;
                        break;

                    // Determine direction by comparing the current touch position with the initial one.
                    case TouchPhase.Moved:
                        direction = touch.position - startPos;
                        break;

                    // Report that a direction has been chosen when the finger is lifted.
                    case TouchPhase.Ended:
                        directionChosen = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (directionChosen)
            {
                // Something that uses the chosen direction...
            }

            if (whileDragging)
            {
                // we make initial calculations from the original local rotation
                transform.localRotation = m_OriginalRotation;

                // read input from mouse or mobile controls
                float inputH;
                float inputV;
                if (relative)
                {
                    inputH = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse X");
                    inputV = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

                    // wrap values to avoid springing quickly the wrong way from positive to negative
                    if (m_TargetAngles.y > 180)
                    {
                        m_TargetAngles.y -= 360;
                        m_FollowAngles.y -= 360;
                    }
                    if (m_TargetAngles.x > 180)
                    {
                        m_TargetAngles.x -= 360;
                        m_FollowAngles.x -= 360;
                    }
                    if (m_TargetAngles.y < -180)
                    {
                        m_TargetAngles.y += 360;
                        m_FollowAngles.y += 360;
                    }
                    if (m_TargetAngles.x < -180)
                    {
                        m_TargetAngles.x += 360;
                        m_FollowAngles.x += 360;
                    }

#if MOBILE_INPUT
            // on mobile, sometimes we want input mapped directly to tilt value,
            // so it springs back automatically when the look input is released.
            if (autoZeroHorizontalOnMobile) {
                m_TargetAngles.y = Mathf.Lerp (-rotationRange.y * 0.5f, rotationRange.y * 0.5f, inputH * .5f + .5f);
            } else {
                m_TargetAngles.y += inputH * rotationSpeed;
            }
            if (autoZeroVerticalOnMobile) {
                m_TargetAngles.x = Mathf.Lerp (-rotationRange.x * 0.5f, rotationRange.x * 0.5f, inputV * .5f + .5f);
            } else {
                m_TargetAngles.x += inputV * rotationSpeed;
            }
#else
                    // with mouse input, we have direct control with no springback required.
                    m_TargetAngles.y += inputH * rotationSpeed;
                    m_TargetAngles.x += inputV * rotationSpeed;
#endif

                    // clamp values to allowed range
                    m_TargetAngles.y = Mathf.Clamp(m_TargetAngles.y, -rotationRange.y * 0.5f, rotationRange.y * 0.5f);
                    m_TargetAngles.x = Mathf.Clamp(m_TargetAngles.x, -rotationRange.x * 1f, rotationRange.x * 0.2f);

                }
                else
                {
                    inputH = -Input.mousePosition.x;
                    inputV = -Input.mousePosition.y;

                    // set values to allowed range
                    m_TargetAngles.y = Mathf.Lerp(-rotationRange.y * 0.5f, rotationRange.y * 0.5f, inputH / Screen.width);
                    m_TargetAngles.x = Mathf.Lerp(-rotationRange.x * 1f, rotationRange.x * 1f, inputV / Screen.height);
                }

                // smoothly interpolate current values to target angles
                m_FollowAngles = Vector3.SmoothDamp(m_FollowAngles, m_TargetAngles, ref m_FollowVelocity, dampingTime);

                // update the actual gameobject's rotation
                transform.localRotation = m_OriginalRotation * Quaternion.Euler(-m_FollowAngles.x, m_FollowAngles.y, 0);

            }
        }

        public void BeginDrag()
        {
            whileDragging = true;
        }

        public void EndDrag()
        {
            whileDragging = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe somebody could help me here it would be pretty awesome!

Grettings from Germany

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm, why not try using this?

```
float rotSpeed = 20;

void OnMouseDrag(){
    float rotX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    float rotY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotSpeed * Mathf.Deg2Rad;

    transform.RotateAround(Vector3.up, -rotX);
   transform.RotateAround(Vector3.right, rotY);
}
```

A simple way of rotating using `touch input` :)

Comment: I tryed to add this to my code but this there is nothing changing on the Surface sadly or do I have to set a new script for this code?

Comment: You need to set this to a new script for you to see.

Comment: This should be `Mathf.Deg2Rad`, not `...Def2...`

Comment: In 2021 you may want to use the non-deprecated transform.Rotate().